# How do I know if a particular skin is not going to always be available to buy?

Tags: league-of-legends

Some Champion skins in League of Legends are only available for a set time period, at which point they are removed from the store and become unavailable for purchase permanently. How does one know if a skin they are saving up for, or waiting to go on sale, will soon be gone?

Comment: Ask Riot. Only way to know for sure, everything else are just guesses.

Comment: Well there is an search option checkbox in the store "Limited availability", this are the "Christmas skins" and such. But as far as I remember they already removed certain skins which where not labeled as such. So its just Riots marketing strategy which they probably won't tell everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One will know anywhere from five days to two weeks in advance, whenever Riot releases a notice (sometimes hidden in patch notes) saying "We will be removing [X Skin] from our store in [X Amount of Time]. Buy it now before it is removed from the store [Forever/Until Next Holiday/PAX/ etc]. We love you, wallet-minions!"

Comment: can you provide a source?

Comment: The Riot Graves skin availability was announced a week before it was released for a weeks' time (Through PAX weekend). There was also the Retiring Classic Skins post - www.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2349423

Comment: @Ender Look at their page history. They don't have an official policy because, usually, most people will not complain about a skin becoming unavailable. However, always assume holiday skins will be permanently gone, I don't know of any that have been up for purchase more than once.

Comment: In the case of some Classic skins, there are rumors revolving around them being acquirable via the upcoming "Achievement System" that's supposed to be released soon.

Answer (score 1):

None of the newly released skins will be permanently unavailable, as per Riot's [skin classification](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1621978) - those are the older Limited Edition skins, while all newer ones are Legacy skins which can be reissued by Riot at their discretion.

As already answered, Riot should have some notice before a skin is removed. There are also some event-specific skins which are unavailable past a time window near the event (e.g. Snowdown skins are bought around Christmas and discontinued sometime early Jan).

There's no easy way to figure out if the skin you are considering is Legacy version; but in general these are more expensive than most other skins - so typically they will be 975 RP and rarely discounted.